# Annotated Step Configuration in Spring Batch, how to test

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I use spring batch with annotations only, I want to test a step which is configured like so:

```
@Bean("findMe")
@Qualifier("findMe")
public Step findMe() {
     return stepBuilderFactory.get("findMe"). ... some step configuration
}
```

Test:

```
@Test
public shouldRunTheJob() {
    JobLauncherTestUtils.launchJob("findMe");
}
```

I was not able to address the job, besides that I was able to test all other levels, how can I address a job annotated like this?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand from your question, you want to test a step and not a job.

Try using the following sample test class for your step test.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = YourClassToTest.class)
public class StepTest {

    @Autowired
    private JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtils;

    @Test
    public void testStep() throws Exception {
       JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncherTestUtils.launchStep("findMe");
       // your test case, e.g. assert something on the jobExecution
    }    
}
```

For more information please refer to the spring batch docs [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/testing.html#testingIndividualSteps).